# JSON Schema not parsing array

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

I have a JSON Schema, using draft-07, trying to accept a string array as a parameter in a POST request (below is my code in the schema):

```
"resources": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "type": "string"
    }
}
```

The problem is, is when I try to call my endpoint where my schema is associated, using the JSON-encoded parameters

```
{
    "resources": ["Wheat", "Meat"]
}
```

I get the following error: "message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unexpected character (\'W\'

However if I call my endpoint where my schema is associated, using the following JSON-encoded parameters

```
{
    "resources": [0, 1]
}
```

It successfully completes, even though I specify the items need to be of type string in my schema.

For clarity I am using AWS Api Gateway.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please post the code?

Comment: JSON parsing errors are not JSON Schema errors.